# My signals are being ignored!

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

So I developed a UI in Glade and am coding the program in Python. For some reason, all of my signals are being ignored! Though I've connected them correctly (I think), clicking on the buttons does absolutely nothing!

Below is the code that I'm using to load the ui and connect the signals. Can anyone see WHY they might be being ignored?

```
class mySampleClass(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.uiFile = "MainWindow.glade"
    self.wTree = gtk.Builder()
    self.wTree.add_from_file(self.uiFile)

    self.window = self.wTree.get_object("winMain")
    if self.window:
        self.window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

        dic = { "on_btnExit_clicked" : self.clickButton, "on_winMain_destroy" : gtk.main_quit }
        self.wTree.connect_signals(dic)
        self.window.show()
    else:
        print "Could not load window"
        sys.exit(1)


def clickButton(self, widget):
    print "You clicked exit!"


def exit(self, widget):
    gtk.main_quit()

def update_file_selection(self, widget, data=None):
    selected_filename = FileChooser.get_filename()
    print selected_filename

if __name__ == "__main__":
MyApp = MySampleClass()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: When I read the title I thought the questions subject was a relationship.

Comment: Does self.wTree.connect_signals(dic) return None?

Comment: Are you sure you set the handlers correctly in glade? The code you posted (with a few typos fixed) worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure that this is the answer, but I know that a number of PyGTK objects cannot send signals themselves - gtk.Image and gtk.Label are two such examples. The solution is to place the widget inside of an event box (gtk.EventBox) and link the events to that.

I do not know if this is the case with tree objects, however. All the same, worth investigating, imho.